# Auth::user()-> non-object

Tags: authentication, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve users First Name from the database so I tried something like this in my provider.php controller but the browser error says "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
$provider = Auth::user()->email;
    return View::make('providers.account')
                    ->with('title', 'Account')
                    ->with('provider', $provider);
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you mind adding full error stack. It can typically be found in app/storage/logs/log-apache2handler-{today}.txt

Comment: is the user logged in? Should you be checking for that before ?

Comment: try wrapping with `if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user is logged in:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
$provider = Auth::user()->email;
    return View::make('providers.account')
                    ->with('title', 'Artsgap Account')
                    ->with('provider', $provider);
}
```

otherwise it will return that error (the object doesn;t exist since there is no logged in user)

Comment: Oh -.- nope i wasn't logged in, but how can you retrieve data from DB sorry silly question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get information for the logged in user, use Ben Dubuisson's answer.

If you are try to get the information for a specified user, do something like:

```
$provider = User::find($id)->email;
```